# Module organization, inheritance, and @classmethods

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to write a class that works kind of like the builtins and some of the other "grown-up" Python stuff I've seen. My Pythonic education is a little spotty, classes-wise, and I'm worried I've got it all mixed up.

I'd like to create a class that serves as a kind of repository, containing a dictionary of unprocessed files (and their names), and a dictionary of processed files (and their names). I'd like to implement some other (sub?)classes that handle things like opening and processing the files. The file handling classes should be able to update the dictionaries in the main class. I'd also like to be able to directly call the various submodules without having to separately instantiate everything, e.g.:

```
import Pythia
p = Pythia()
p.FileManager.addFile("/path/to/some/file")
```

or even

```
Pythia.FileManager.addFile("/path/to/some/file")
```

I've been looking around at stuff about `@classmethod` and `super` and such, but I can't say I entirely understand it. I'm also beginning to suspect that I might have the whole chain of inheritance backwards--that what I think of as my main class should actually be the child class of the handling and processing classes. I'm also wondering whether this would all work better as a package, but that's a separate, very intimidating issue.

Here's my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import os
class Pythia(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_files = {}
        self.parsed_files = {}
        self.FileManger = FileManager()
    def listf(self,fname,f):
        if fname in self.raw_files.keys():
            _isRaw = "raw"
        elif fname in self.parsed_files.keys():
            _isRaw = "parsed"
        else:
            return "Error: invalid file"
        print "{} ({}):{}...".format(fname,_isRaw,f[:100])

    def listRaw(self,n=None):
        max = n or len(self.raw_files.items())
        for item in self.raw_files.items()[:max]:
            listf(item[0],item[1])

    def listParsed(self,n=None):
        max = n or len(self.parsed_files.items())
        for item in self.parsed_files.items()[:max]:
            listf(item[0],item[1])

class FileManager(Pythia):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def addFile(self,f,name=None,recurse=True,*args):
        if name:
            fname = name
        else:
            fname = ".".join(os.path.basename(f).split(".")[:-1])
        if os.path.exists(f):
            if not os.path.isdir(f):
                with open(f) as fil:
                    Pythia.raw_files[fname] = fil.read()
            else:
                print "{} seems to be a directory.".format(f)
                if recurse == False:
                    return "Stopping..."
                elif recurse == True:
                    print "Recursively navingating directory {}".format(f)
                    addFiles(dir,*args)
                else:
                    recurse = raw_input("Recursively navigate through directory {}? (Y/n)".format(f))
                    if recurse[0].lower() == "n":
                        return "Stopping..."
                    else:
                        addFiles(dir,*args)
        else:
            print "Error: file or directory not found at {}".format(f)
    def addFiles(self,directory=None,*args):
        if directory:
            self._recursivelyOpen(directory)
        def argHandler(arg):
            if isinstance(arg,str):
                self._recursivelyOpen(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg,tuple):
                self.addFile(arg[0],arg[1])
            else:
                print "Warning: {} is not a valid argument...skipping..."
                pass
        for arg in args:
            if not isinstance(arg,(str,dict)):
                if len(arg) > 2:
                    for subArg in arg:
                        argHandler(subArg)
                else:
                    argHandler(arg)
            elif isinstance(arg,dict):
                for item in arg.items():
                    argHandler(item)
            else:
                argHandler(arg)
    def _recursivelyOpen(self,f):
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            l = [os.path.join(f,x) for x in os.listdir(f) if x[0] != "."]
            for x in l:
                _recursivelyOpen(x)
        else:
            addFile(f)
```

Comment: If you `import Pythia`, that's a module, not a class. So you can't do `Pythia()`. You could have a class named `Pythia` in the module also named `Pythia`, in which case you could do `Pythia.Pythia()`. But you're better off avoiding the confusion by calling the module `pythia` (as PEP8 suggests).

Comment: One more thing: `self.FileManger = FileManager()` is a really bad idea. Naming a class and an instance of that class the same thing is guaranteed to lead to confusion. (If you follow PEP8 as Eevee suggests, this never even comes up—`file_manager` is a reasonable name for a generic `FileManager` instance. But if you don't, you need some other style for naming such things, like Apple-style `aFileManager`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)'s guidelines.  Module names, variable names, and function names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`; only class names should be `CamelCase`.  Following your code is a little difficult otherwise.  :)

You're muddying up OO concepts here: you have a parent class that contains an instance of a subclass.

Does a `FileManager` do mostly what a `Pythia` does, with some modifications or extensions?  Given that the two only work together, I'd guess not.

I'm not quite sure what you ultimately want this to look like, but I don't think you need inheritance at all.  `FileManager` can be its own class, `self.file_manager` on a `Pythia` instance can be an instance of `FileManager`, and then `Pythia` can delegate to it if necessary.  That's not far from how you're using this code already.

Build small, independent pieces, *then* worry about how to plug them into each other.

---

Also, some bugs and style nits:

- You call `_recursivelyOpen(x)` but forgot the `self.`.
- Single space after commas.
- Watch out for `max` as a variable name: it's also the name of a builtin function.
- Avoid type-checking (`isinstance`) if you can help it.  It's extra-hard to follow your code when it does a dozen different things depending on argument types.  Have very clear argument types, and create helper functions that accept different arguments if necessary.
- You have `Pythia.raw_files[fname]` inside `FileManager`, but `Pythia` is a class, and it doesn't have a `raw_files` attribute anyway.
- You check if `recurse` is `True`, then `False`, then...  something else.  When is it something else?  Also, you should use `is` instead of `==` for testing against the builtin singletons like this.

Comment: +1, except you're still missing the big problem: He's doing `import Pythia`, then `Pythia()`. I'm not sure whether he was looking for `from Pythia import Pythia` in place of the first or `Pythia.Pythia()` in place of the second, and your suggestions will make the distinction obvious—but he still needs to fix that one way or the other.

Comment: pff, so he is.  i think that's hypothetical, though, and not actual code he's tried running yet.

Comment: Yes, he says it's code he wants to be able to run. And if you read that paragraph, he seems to be mixing up modules and classes even further there (e.g., referring to `FileManager` as a submodule).

Comment: The code I have here is the result of a fair amount of trying to run things in the interpreter, then trying to patch/modify things without having a very clear idea of what I was doing...I try not to run immediately to StackOverflow, lest I get totally embarrassed by people who actually know what's going on.
I should also admit that I'm not up on my PEP specifications...I was taught that the camelCase/underscores distinction was a matter of personal style. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: here's a secret: we didn't always know what's going on  :)

Comment: Also--what should I do instead of isinstance? One of the things I'm trying to do with this code is clean up some inconveniently-formatted XML files. I'm disinclined to force hypothetical future users' hands regarding how exactly the files 'get in.' Should I just break the various type-dependent things I'm doing in addFiles/argHandler into separate, clearly-labeled helper functions?

Comment: i would have an `add_file` that accepts a filename and whatever other special metadata (like a name override), an `add_files` that accepts only a list of filenames, and an `add_directory` that deals with recursing (which, btw, you could do non-recursively with `os.walk`).  if user code wants to do something fancy with e.g. a dict of files, it's really easy for them to just call `add_file` directly from a loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot here and you are probably best to educate yourself some more.

For your intended usage:

```
import Pythia
p = Pythia()
p.file_manager.addFile("/path/to/some/file")
```

A class structure like this would work:

```
class FileManager(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def addFile(self, file):
        # Your code
        self.parent.raw_files[file] = file

    def addFiles(self, files)
        # Your code
        for file in files:
            self.parent.raw_files[file] = file

class Pythia(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_manager = FileManager(self)
```

However there are a lot of options.  You should write some client code first to work out what you want, then implement your class/objects to match that.  I don't tend to ever use inheritance in python, it is not really required due to pythons duck typing.

Also if you want a method to be called without instantiating the class use staticmethod, not classmethod. For example:

```
class FileManager(object):
    @staticmethod
    def addFiles(files):
        pass
```

Comment: nine times out of ten, a `@staticmethod` should just be a module-level function.

Comment: @Eevee: +1. Exactly. The best rule of thumb for novices (especially recent Java immigrants) is: Use `@classmethod` for alternate constructors; use `@staticmethod` never. Eventually you learn exceptions, but until you're ready to learn exactly how they really work, the rule of thumb serves well enough.